# How to merge two files with the same column value in bash

Tags: bash, csv, merge

I have 2 csv files, these are their contents.

**file1(23 fields)**

```
data11,data12,ID1,data14...

data21,data22,ID2,data24...

data31,data32,ID3,data34...
```

**file2 (22 fields)**

```
ID1,value12,value13,...

ID1,value22,value23,...

ID1,value32,value33,...

ID2,value42,value43,... 

ID3,value52,value53,...
```

The output should be...

**OUTPUT:**

```
 data11,data12,ID1,data14,...,value12,value13

 data11,data12,ID1,data14,...,value22,value23

 data11,data12,ID1,data14,...,value32,value33

 data21,data22,ID2,data24,...,value42,value43

 data31,data32,ID3,data34,...,value52,value53
```

Can anyone help me to get this output using `awk` or any `bash` built-ins?
Thanks!

Comment: is this `,...,` implies multiple intermediate columns? What is the number of fields in each file?

Comment: Yes, you're right. For file 1 there are 23 fields and for file 2 there are 22 fields

Comment: can you post the input fragment with ALL fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `join` ..Specify the column order required for output after `-o` eg: 1.1 refers 1st column of 1st (`file1`) file. It is also required to pre-sort the input files

```
join -t "," -1 3 -2 1  -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2,2.3 
<( sort -t "," -k3 /tmp/file1 ) <( sort -t "," -k1 /tmp/file2 )
```

Comment: But in my case ID is not an integer. It's a string of random characters. can join still support it?

Comment: Yes, we are sorting both inputs here based on the column which is not necessarily a numeric sort. try using this and let me know.Some tweaks could be required to prepare the input files.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault to misunderstand ur problem, try the following cmd, it should be what u want:

```
for line1 in `cat file1`;do id=`echo $line1|awk -F ',' '{print $3}'`;\
awk -v id=$id -v line1=$line1 -F ',' '($1==id){print line1","$0}' file2;done
```

the output of this cmd is

```
data11,data12,ID1,data14...,ID1,value12,value13,...
data11,data12,ID1,data14...,ID1,value22,value23,...
data11,data12,ID1,data14...,ID1,value32,value33,...
data21,data22,ID2,data24...,ID2,value42,value43,... 
data31,data32,ID3,data34...,ID3,value52,value53,...
```

and if u don't want the repeated column of ID*, u can do this like

```
for line1 in `cat file1`;do id=`echo $line1|awk -F ',' '{print $3}'`;\
awk -v id=$id -v line1=$line1 -F ',' '($1==id){printf "%s",line1;\
for(i=2;i<NF;i++) printf ",%s",$i;print ","$NF}' file2;done
```

it won't print ID* in file2

```
data11,data12,ID1,data14...,value12,value13,...
data11,data12,ID1,data14...,value22,value23,...
data11,data12,ID1,data14...,value32,value33,...
data21,data22,ID2,data24...,value42,value43,... 
data31,data32,ID3,data34...,value52,value53,...
```

----------wrong answer prior to updated---------

https://www.computerhope.com/unix/upaste.htm
HI,

u can use `paste` cmd to join related lines of different files

please use `man paste` cmd for detailed usage

Comment: But i think this problem is more complicated. I think I can't use paste cmd here, because there are some column checking.

Comment: @JaneS. So sorry to misunderstand your problem,  please check my updated answer.